# Angular 2 : Logout all open tabs automatically when user logs out in one of them

Tags: angular

I have created Login page, based on sessionstorage. On loading the page I have checked the value of sessionstorage. If I opened the web page in more than one tab and then I logout from any one of the tabs, all the remaining pages should logout automatically.

Please help me to run a script, when user view the page or say any other way to solve this problem.

On click of logout button

```
logout() {

 const userLoggedOut = this.loginService.changeStatusLogout(this.isAuthenticated.getLoginStatus(),                                                            this.isAuthenticated.getLoggedInUserID());
if (userLoggedOut) {
  const link = ['login'];
  this.router.navigate(link);
 }
}

changeStatusLogout(status: boolean, userID){
  if (userID && status) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('userID');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('userGroup');
    sessionStorage.removeItem('userLogedIn');
  return true;
  }
}

getLoginStatus() {
    const checkStaus = sessionStorage.getItem('userLogedIn');
    if (checkStaus === 'true') {
    return this.userLoggedIn = true;
    }
}

getLoggedInUserIDGroup() {
  const loggedInUserGroup = sessionStorage.getItem('userGroup');
  return loggedInUserGroup;
  }
```

Comment: Think you can just load the component after login again and when loading set all tabs on not visible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Storage events to be notified when localStorage values are changed.

```
function storageChange (event) {
if(event.key === 'logged_in') {
    alert('Logged in: ' + event.newValue)
}}  window.addEventListener('storage', storageChange, false)
```

If, for example, one of the tabs logs out:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('logged_in', false)
```

Then all other tabs will receive a StorageEvent, and an alert will appear:

```
Logged in: false
```